# Use Snipping tool to snip Snipping tool in window mode?

Tags: windows-10

I want to use snipping tool on its own in window mode. If yes how can it be done. I need to snip snipping tool itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [snipping tool](https://www.getcloudapp.com/uses/microsoft-snipping-tool) and then use print screen or the built-in screenshot capabilities to take a screenshot of the screenshot inception style.